# Splitting <ion-view> into frames

Tags: angularjs, frameset, ionic-framework

[image]

So currently the blue frame content is `<ion-tabs>`, 
and the green and orange frames are unseperated and hosted inside `<ion-view><ion-content>`;
How can I seperate them into two different frames, so scrolling on either of them won't affect the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is, you can use two `<ion-scroll>` inside `<ion-content>` like:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
     <ion-scroll direction="xy" style="width:100%;height:30%;">
       <Map></Map>
     </ion-scroll>
     <ion-scroll direction="y" style="width:100%;height:70%;">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
     </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Here, you need to set height of ion-scroll and its content to work it properly.